# Difference between Android AsyncTask and realm.executeTransactionAsync

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, realm

I'm new in Realm world and I'm in trouble. I have a animation in my Android application and is shown while have a database process running and my animation is freezing.
I think can be because my database process in running into a AsyncTask like that:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    //HERE IS MY CODE TO SAVE DATA
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                }
            }.execute();
```

I would like to know if have some difference between Android's AsyncTask and realm.executeTransactionAsync(...). The method executeTransactionAsync prevent UI freezing?

Answer (score 3):

Animation runs on main thread, and AsyncTask does not (runs on a separate thread).

> my animation is freezing. I think can be because my database process in running into a AsyncTask

It is very unlikely that this is the case.

Doing the database transaction in an async transaction provided by Realm, is of course better (at least concept wise) than wrapping the transaction in an asynctask you made yourself.

Switching out your asynctask for an async transaction will not fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem has nothing to do with differences between `AsyncTask` and `realm.executeTransactionAsync`, They do the same job (if you extend `AsyncTask` in the right way), If you are sure that all transactions are done in background you should look for the problem somewhere else (some long task that is running on the main thread), There's nothing more to say with code you posted but as a tip:

Both `AsyncTask` and `Realm` (async transactions) use `ThreadPoolExecutor` with some differences:

**Relam:**

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2 + 1;
private static final int QUEUE_SIZE = 100;

ThreadPoolExecutor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, CORE_POOL_SIZE,
     0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, //terminated idle thread
     new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(QUEUE_SIZE));
```

**AsyncTask:**

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;
private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
    }
};

private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);

public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
        = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used realm, but according to the documentation below "executeTransactionAsync" is used to "Asynchronously update objects on a background thread", so I think that answers your question.

Source:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/